# Android Studio: Error finding symbol "Spinner"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner

I've been messing around with Android Studio lately. I tried to make an app to get user input and store it in a database, but it keeps giving me this error:

```
    error: cannot find symbol
        Spinner spinnerName = findViewById(R.id.nameOfTheDropdown); // It's in my MainActivity Class
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable nameOfTheDropdown
  location: class id
```

I've been struggling with this for a very long time.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are missing R it could be R.id.nameOfTheDropdown make sure nameOfTheDropdown  exists in the layout

Comment: It shows the same after adding and importing R.

Comment: Edit: I solved it by passing (Spinner) before findViewById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Comment: How do you know it is spinner? It is just a wild guess and could be a comment ...

Comment: @AgentP It's just type safe declaration and op asks for solve the problem. It may be questioners fault for bad declaration.

Comment: Although your solution might solve the problem, please add an explanation as to why it works to make it more effective